# In Titanium how do I fetch data from inside a TableViewRow?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I've added a ImageView and a Label to a TableViewRow, I've attached an on click event listener, so I can get the row, but how can I access the label inside of that row?

Is there a way to find the objects added to the row object?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug on android:

https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32238-titanium-mobile/tickets/868-implement-tableview-rowchildren#ticket-868-3